# PLSQL - convert UTF-8 NVARCHAR2 to VARCHAR2

Tags: utf-8, plsql

I have a table with a column configured as NVARCHAR2, I'm able save the string in UTF-8 without any issues.
But the application the calls the value does not fully support UTF-8.
This means that the string is passed to the database and back after the string is converted into HTML letter code. Each letter in the string is converted to such HTML code.

I'm looking for an easier solution.
I've considered converting it to BASE64, but it contains various characters which are considered illegal in the application.
In addition tried using HEXTORAW & RAWTOHEX.

None of the above helped.

If the column contains 'κόσμε' I need to find a way to convert/encode it to something else, but the decode should be possible to do from the HTML running the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ASCIISTR function, it will convert it in something similar as JSON encodes unicode strings (it's actually the same, except "\" is used instead of "\u") and then when you receive it back from front end try using UNISTR to convert it back to unicode.

ASCIISTR: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions006.htm

UNISTR: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions204.htm

```
SELECT ASCIISTR(N'κόσμε') FROM DUAL;
SELECT UNISTR('\03BA\1F79\03C3\03BC\03B5') FROM DUAL;
```